# How to find the constellation in which the sun is located using the night sky map?

Tags: observational-astronomy, coordinate, time, night-sky

The following sky map was given as part of practice problems in my Astronomy course
[image]

The moon is in its first quarter phase. I am supposed to find the approximate date and time of the year in which this photograph was taken. I am clueless as to how to proceed so any help is greatly appreciated. I am new to Astronomy StackExchange, and I apologize in advance if I have made any mistakes.

Comment: The question is really asking if you understand what is meant by First Quarter Moon. That is, where is the First Quarter Moon located relative to the Sun. If you know that, then knowing that the Moon is in Gemini tells you that the Sun is in X, and the Sun is in X around the date of M. Please post an answer when you work it out.